# Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Been googling this error message, but havent been able to find a solution that works for me. 
I've created an mvc4 application using entity framework, and im trying to run 'enable-migrations' on nuget, but i get the error:

Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

Im using the full version of SQL server 2008 on my localmachine, and i added my database using the server explorer and copied the connection string from the properties

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=CQTT4323;Initial database=JBSMonitor;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The wierd thing is that there is no attachdbfilename property at all, as i understand it is not necessary on sql server full?

Any clues

EDIT:

When i changed the name of my connection from "Default connection" to another name and used that name in my DbContext everything worked fine. Probably it uses another "Default connection" ?

Answer (score 0):

replace the entire string with following

```
Data Source=yourmachinename\sql_server_name;Initial Catalog=JBSMonitor;Integrated Security=true
```